# Mostrar esconder conteúdo quando clicado em um id específico

Tags: jquery

Vamos supor que eu tenho dois links

```
<a href="#pessoa1">link1</a>
<a href="#pessoa2">link2</a>
```

O conteúdo mostrado será somente referente ao link clicado e quando clicar em outro link o conteúdo aberto atualmente será fechado

```
<div id="pessoa1"></div>
<div id="pessoa2"></div>
```

Código em jquery tentei usar [id^="pessoa"] para pegar o conteúdo pelo numero mas não funciona, alguma dica?

```
<script>
$('a').click(function(e){
    $('[id^="pessoa"]').show("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria desta forma, pegando o `href` do elemento clicado, que é o `id` da respectiva `div`:

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
   $("div[id^='pessoa']").hide();
   var id = $(this).attr("href");
    $(id).show("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
div[id^='pessoa']{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#pessoa1">link1</a>
<a href="#pessoa2">link2</a>
<br>
<div id="pessoa1">p1</div>
<div id="pessoa2">p2</div>
```

> O `return false;` não é necessário.

Comment: Legal, só não entendi uma coisa, o [id^='pessoa'] funciona assim no css? Outra coisa como fechar o conteúdo aberto qdo clicar em outro?

Comment: Sim, funciona no CSS. Irá ocultar os ids que começam com "pessoa".... vou alterar a resposta para esconder o outro.

Comment: Pra ficar mais específico, vc pode fazer `div[id^='pessoa']`

Comment: @user4451 Resposta atualizada. Vc pode usar o mesmo seletor no jQuery para ocultar as divs.

Comment: Poxa, que massa, mto obrigado, tava quase conseguindo mas faltava só uma coisinha ou outra no código hehehe!!!

Comment: @user4451 Agora esse `return false;` não precisa. Pode retirar.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu, não deixe de marcar ✔. =] Valeu!